# Xml parsing in windows 7 for xml data from world bank

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

This is the link for  my xml data

http://api.worldbank.org/countries/IND/indicators/EN.ATM.CO2E.PC?per_page=10&date=2005:2012

i am using the following code to parse it and display but unable to do so.

```
 public void Getinfo()
    {
        try
        {
           String url = http://api.worldbank.org/countries/IND/indicators/EN.ATM.CO2E.PC?per_page=10&date=2005:2012";
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.OpenReadCompleted += wc_OpenReadCompleted;
            wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));



        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please retry unable to access Data");

        }
    }
    private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error + "");
            return;
        }
        using (Stream s = e.Result)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(s);
            XNamespace wb = "http://www.worldbank.org";

            foreach (var node in doc.Element(wb+"data").Element(wb+"data").Elements(wb+"date"))
            {
               String chk = node.Value.ToString();
               String year1 = "2007";
                if (chk == year1)
                {
                    foreach (var node1 in doc.Element(wb+"data").Element(wb+"data").Elements(wb+"value"))
                    {
                        info1.Text = node1.Value.ToString();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Saying you are unable to do so doesn't give much to go on.

Comment: I am not able to access all the values in the xml file. I am able to access only the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your Linq request:

What you are doing here:

You take the first **data** element, then you take the first **data** element again in the previous, and then you take all the **date** in that second **data** element.

```
data --> enter here
-- data --> then here
-- -- date --> and take all the date element in the parent data node
               (but there is only one date element per data)
-- data
-- -- date
```

What you want to do is:

Take all the **data** element at the second level, but don't take the whole element, just the first **date** element of each **data** element.

```cs
foreach (var date in doc.Element(wb + "data").Elements(wb + "data").Select(data => data.Element(wb + "date")))
{
    ...
}
```

What you want to achieve isn't clear for me, but then if you need the **value** element in the same **data** element, maybe it isn't necessary to return only the **date**.

Also, why do you use a second foreach statement? Once again, you'll only receive one element with that request. I guess what you want to do is something like this:

```cs
foreach (var node in doc.Element(wb + "data").Elements(wb + "data"))
{
    if("2007".Equals(node.Element(wb + "date").Value){
        info1.Text = node.Element(wb + "value").Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things missing there in your attempt to get the data.  The first is in your use of the namespace. This parses through the various elements and gets the one from 2007 like you have.

This isn't a 1 for 1 replacement of your code, but it's meant to show you how to traverse the tree.  Hopefully, this will point you in the right direction.

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp\wb.xml");

var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.worldbank.org");

// Get the root element
var root = doc.Element(ns.GetName("data"));

//Get a collection of the elements underneath the root that are called "data"
var elements = root.Elements(ns.GetName("data"));

//Select only those that are from 2007
var selectedElements = elements.Where(e=>e.Element(ns.GetName("date")).Value.Equals("2007"));

//Iterate through each one
selectedElements.ToList().ForEach(x=>
    {
        var val = decimal.Parse(x.Element(ns.GetName("value")).Value);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Value is: {0}", val);
    });
```